# $.ajax fails in Cross-domain request even with apache proxy

Tags: ajax, apache, cross-domain

I am suppose to reach the URL below and to verify that i am getting HTTP status 200 or something else.
http://AAAAAAAAAA.com:59060/eddUtilityService/eddUtilityService.wsdl

As none of the existing questions on cross-domain is not answering my issue.  So please don't ignore this.

This is the ajax call I am making from my HTML file.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/l2/eddUtilityService/eddUtilityService.wsdl",        
    type: "HEAD",
    async: false,
    contentType: "JSONP",
    success: function(data){
        console.log("SUCCESS for ajax call ");
        return data.responseCode;
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("Error for ajax call "+jqXHR.status+"-- "+textStatus+"--"+errorThrown);
        return jqXHR.status;
    }
```

However i have my proxy setup in Apache is as below;

```
            RewriteRule /l2/eddUtilityService/eddUtilityService.wsdl http://AAAAAAAAAA.com:59060/eddUtilityService/eddUtilityService.wsdl
            ProxyPassReverse /l2/ http://AAAAAAAAAA.com:59060/
```

But i am getting the error as result and jqXHR.status is 0 and also its readyStatus is equal to 0.

Could somebody say what's wrond in the above code?
I have also tried with contentType="text/xml" and "application/text" just json.  But results are same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about apache proxy so I'm not sure if this will be of much help but the HTTP response headers from the server should have this header: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" to allow the cross-origin request. You might want to check the configuration of your proxy

Comment: Thanks for the reply Inohika. But I cannot see the server end configs, as AAAAAAAAAA.com is running on a different machine and i don't have control over it. So not sure that "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is set in server response. GUess not.  But is there any way we can compensate it by doing something from client side itself?